# Ubuntu 22.04n is not properly detecting built-in speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, speakers

I'm running a Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot. While sound works perfectly on the Windows 10 boot, no sound is emitted on speakers in the Ubuntu boot (connecting a headset or external speaker via Bluetooth on either boot does work). Moreover when looking at the 'speaker' that Ubuntu is trying to use, it seems that a microphone is being used instead.

Detected input and output devices. No input or output devices are detected other than those shown. Note that the blue activity indicator under the output device section reacts to sound input, while the red indicator under the input device section does not.

[image: Detected input and output devices. No input or output devices are detected other than those shown. Note that the blue activity indicator under the output device section reacts to sound input, while the red indicator under the input device section does not.]

The name for the in-built speakers in the Windows 10 boot matches neither the name for the input device nor the name for the output device as are displayed in the Ubuntu boot, it is something along the lines of 'alto-falantes', which is just Portuguese for speaker.

Believing that I'd already found out, I proceeded to fuck around and installed PipeWire in case that had the necessary drivers. It did not.

Below are the command line logs I've looked at in search of the problem.

Results of arecord -l:

[image: arecord -l]

Results of pulseaudio:

[image: pulseaudio]

Results of pipewire:

[image: pipewire]

alsa-info (filtered, feel free to ask for any relevant parts I omitted)

```
!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k6.5.0-21-generic
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp (card 0)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - No


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.-940XFG-P03RGS-NP940XFG_KA1AR


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51ca] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
    * : 


!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card0
Driver: /sys/bus/platform/drivers/skl_hda_dsp_generic
Tree:


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 13 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/hwC0D2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Mar  7 09:24 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D1c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D4p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D5p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D6c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/pcmC0D7c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar  6 20:12 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Mar  6 20:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 340 Mar  6 20:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Mar  6 20:12 pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 6: DMIC (*) []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 7: DMIC16kHz (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_tad
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
af_alg
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bluetooth
bnep
br_netfilter
bridge
btbcm
btintel
btmtk
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cec
cfg80211
clk_tps68470
cmac
cmdlinepart
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_buddy
drm_display_helper
drm_kms_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
efi_pstore
ghash_clmulni_intel
gpio_keys
hid
hid_generic
hid_logitech_dj
hid_logitech_hidpp
hid_multitouch
hid_sensor_als
hid_sensor_custom
hid_sensor_hub
hid_sensor_iio_common
hid_sensor_trigger
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_hid_acpi
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i915
idma64
industrialio
industrialio_triggered_buffer
input_leds
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cstate
intel_ish_ipc
intel_ishtp
intel_ishtp_hid
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_skl_int3472_discrete
intel_skl_int3472_tps68470
intel_tcc_cooling
intel_uncore_frequency
intel_uncore_frequency_common
ip_tables
irqbypass
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kfifo_buf
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libarc4
libcrc32c
llc
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
mei_pxp
msr
mtd
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_tables
nfnetlink
nft_chain_nat
nft_compat
nls_iso8859_1
nvme
nvme_common
nvme_core
overlay
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_tigerlake
polyval_clmulni
polyval_generic
ppdev
processor_thermal_device
processor_thermal_device_pci
processor_thermal_mbox
processor_thermal_rapl
processor_thermal_rfim
rapl
rc_core
rfcomm
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
snd
snd_compress
snd_ctl_led
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_ext_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hrtimer
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_intel_sdw_acpi
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_dmic
snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_sof
snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink
snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_probes
snd_sof_utils
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soc_button_array
soundcore
soundwire_bus
soundwire_cadence
soundwire_generic_allocation
soundwire_intel
spi_intel
spi_intel_pci
spi_nor
stp
thunderbolt
tps68470_regulator
ttm
typec
typec_ucsi
ucsi_acpi
usbhid
veth
video
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------



!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                                          1.2.5.1-2                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                               1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.10                     all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils
```

alsamixer (you will note that there is a single item on it, this was not the case when using pulseaudio, which I cannot replicate.

[image: alsamixer (you will note that there is a single item on it, this was not the case when using pulseaudio, which I cannot replicate)]

I am happy to keep either pulseaudio or PipeWire as my default sound server system, as long as at least one of them actually manages to emit sound.